# update the field of 1 object with the other object when the record is created on lookup relation

Tags: formula

I have 2 objects object1__c and object2__c. the object2__c has a lookup to object1__c now I need to update the custom date field on object1__C with the createddate system protected field whenever a object2__c record is created. I tried to do it using the formula field using relationship name but it doesnt work.

custom date field=relationshipname__r.CreatedDate

Is the trigger only way to do this? any workflow or formula can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with process builder, I just double checked in my Developer org where I have 2 custom objects. One has a lookup to the other and on creation of the child it updates the parent.

[image: relationship]
[image: ProcessBuilderUpdate]

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

After reading @jenny's answer of doing this using Process Builder, its best to use Point and Click instead of coding.

**Original:**

First of all, a little clarification of lookup and availibility of fields of lookup object in formula field.

Object2 having Object1 lookup means you can access the fields on Object1 in formula field of Object2 but not in reverse.

Coming to your problem if you want to populate date field in Object1 whenever a Object2 record is created, you should go with trigger. But a potential problem will be the Object1 record date field will get updated every time a new Object2 record is created with Object1 record lookup.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Both of these answers should be combined and this one details potential issues and a way to do it with triggers, yet Jenni's shows process builder but no discussion of issue. So OP take both of these answers into account